# Sleep() within Tick() cycle

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a snippet:

```
func TestTicks(t *testing.T) {
    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(600 * time.Millisecond) {
            log.Println("Tick")
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(5000 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

It makes sense that I get 8 lines printed (5000 div 600 = 8):

```
2020/04/15 14:51:08 Tick
2020/04/15 14:51:09 Tick
2020/04/15 14:51:09 Tick
2020/04/15 14:51:10 Tick
2020/04/15 14:51:10 Tick
2020/04/15 14:51:11 Tick
2020/04/15 14:51:12 Tick
2020/04/15 14:51:12 Tick
```

However, it gets not too clear when I add `Sleep()` inside:

```
func TestTicks(t *testing.T) {
    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(600 * time.Millisecond) {
            log.Println("Tick")
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(5000 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

I expect it to be printed 4 times (5000 div 1100 = 4). But it actually still gets printed 8 times:

```
2020/04/15 14:53:17 Tick
2020/04/15 14:53:18 Tick
2020/04/15 14:53:18 Tick
2020/04/15 14:53:19 Tick
2020/04/15 14:53:19 Tick
2020/04/15 14:53:20 Tick
2020/04/15 14:53:21 Tick
2020/04/15 14:53:21 Tick
```

Why doesn't the internal `Sleep()` affect the execution?

If I modify it even further:

```
func TestTicks(t *testing.T) {
    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(1000 * time.Millisecond) {
            log.Println("Tick")
            time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(5000 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

It gets printed 4 times, while I expect it to be printed only 2 (5000 div 2000 = 2).

I think I'm misunderstanding how `Sleep()` and `for range time.Tick()` things work together...

Comment: Clocks keep ticking even while you sleep (or are otherwise not listening).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time.Tick` creates a timer that ticks at a given frequency.  Those ticks get sent on a channel.  `time.Tick` returns that channel.  So this is more or less equivalent:

```
func TestTicks(t *testing.T) {
    go func() {
        c := time.Tick(600 * time.Millisecond)
        for range c {
            log.Println("Tick")
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(5000 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Note that the ticks that *arrive on* channel `c` are being sent from a third (invisible, system-provided) goroutine.

If you now add your `time.Sleep` call to your anonymous goroutine, do you expect this to affect the system goroutine that sends ticks on channel `c`?  (If so, why?)

Assuming you *don't* expect that—that you expect that the system goroutine will continue to wake once every 600 ms and attempt to stuff a time value into `c` using:

```
now = time.Now()
select {
    case c <- now:
    default:
}
```

—then why would you expect anything different with the `for range time.Tick(arg)` variant?  The function `time.Tick(arg)` is only called once, whether or not you store its return value in a variable named `c`.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I kinda forgot that there should be some third routine that is actually pushing messages to the time-channel.